# Determining if the binary operation gives a group structure

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let * be defined on $2\Bbb{Z}=\{2n\mid n\in \Bbb{Z}\}$ by letting $a * b=a+b$.

I've managed to determine that the operation is closed under $*$ and is associative. It's determining if the operation has an identity element and an inverse element that's the problem.

Here's my solution for the identity element:

Assume that the operation has an identity element $e\in G$ and let $a, b\in 2\Bbb{Z}$ such that $a*b=a$. Consider the element $-b$. It follows that $a+b+(-b)=a$.

I'm not sure how I'd find an inverse element and I'm not sure if my solution of the identity element is right.. Please advise.

Comment: What could be the inverse of, say, $2$? What is the identity element $e$ now here? You did not give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider $2\mathbb Z$ as a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. Then, what can you say?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a * b = a$ then $a+b=a$.

Comment: So adding $-b$ is a decent solution for finding an identity element?

Comment: No. You want to add something to $a$ so that it does not change. If you add $-b$ you get $a=a-b$.

Comment: Could the identity element be $a-b$? That way $a=a-b$. And when plugged back in $a+b=(a-b)+b=a$

Comment: @ErinA it is 0, since we are in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Got it! So that means the inverse is $-a$.

Comment: @ErinA Yes, keep in mind that you are working with addition of integers. If you had some other group you should adjust it to that.